# screan cappture using Media Foundation

Tags: windows, python-3.x, media, pywin32

I want to use Media Foundation with python. Is it possible I didn’t played much with win 32 for python and I don’t know if there is a way to access this library’s features using python. 
The reason for this is I want to achieve fast fraimrate while capturing the screen.  And I can’t do that with pil module in python. 
The situation  is that I am  nearly blind I am using screan reader how ever I have some vision and I want to write a program for my self to better track the mouse on the videos. If you have good suggestion doing  that with python I am more then  happy to read them. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can say that it is not easy resolve your task, because Media Foundation uses C code library, C code interfaces and C code constants. However, it is possible write wrapper code on Python for low level access, or access via COM interface. So, I have a project [Capturing Live-video from Web-camera on Windows 7 and Windows 8](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776058/Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-an?fid=1860631&fr=76#_articleTop) -this project uses Media Foundation for capture live video from camera - in comments you can find the next message:
"Hi,

I'd like to share a 64-bit version of this library and a Python wrapper.

You can find the project pyvideoinput on:
https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyvideoinput[GitHub - pyvideoinput]

Best,
Michael" - it means that there is a Python wrapper for project with Media Foundation. However, this Python wrapper does not include capturing the screen - you must research it by your self.

The second way - you can try my another project [CaptureManager SDK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK) - this project uses Media Foundation for capture live video from camera and it HAS screen capture support. CaptureManager is written in form of COM object and has some supporting on Python - you can get demo program by [CaptureManagerSDKPythonDemo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#twentysecondemoprogram).

So, you can use there projects for begin.

Regards.

Comment: thanks for suggestions how ever the github page does not work.